# How to capture output from Python smtp debug server

Tags: python, django, email

I'm trying to write unittests for some custom Django email backends, and to test it against a "real" smtp server, I'm trying to use Python's built-in smtpd debugging server by running:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

My unittest basically looks like:

```
class Tests(TestCase):

    @override_settings(EMAIL_BACKEND='mycustombackend')
    @override_settings(EMAIL_HOST='localhost')
    @override_settings(EMAIL_PORT='1025')
    def test_backend(self):
        from django.core import mail
        mail.send_mail(
                subject='Subject here',
                message='Here is the message.',
                from_email='from@example.com',
                recipient_list=['to@example.com'],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
```

and when I run this, the smtpd process outputs the email content correctly.

However, when I try and capture that so I can confirm it in my unittest, I get nothing. I've tried using the `subprocess` package, to launch the process and read the output via pipes, but it never receives any output.

I thought I was using subprocess incorrectly, so as a last resort, I tried launching the process with:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025 > /tmp/smtpd.log
```

and reading the log file. However, even with that, no output is ever written to the file.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and spent 2 days trying to figure out what's going on. I tried running both

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

and

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025 > mail.log
```

from one of my integration tests with `subprocess`, but it didn't work. While experimenting with it through REPL I noticed that first read from the pipe that is opened for us by `subprocess` hangs. After I kill it, next read actually returns the data. So I started investigating what's in the stream. But as I had no luck in 2 hours, I ended up rolling my own wrapper around `SMTPServer` that writes to the file, and got myself up and running.

Here is the wrapper class (`process_message` is an abstract method that is required of `smtpd.SMTPServer`'s child class to be runnable by `smtpd` module):

```
# test_smtpd.py

import smtpd

SMTP_DUMPFILE = '/tmp/mail.log'

class SMTPTestServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):
    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data, **kwargs):
        with open(SMTP_DUMPFILE, 'w') as f:
            f.write(data)
```

I run it with

```
python -m smtpd -n -c test_smtpd.SMTPTestServer localhost:1025
```

While this does not directly answer your question, it is an easy workaround, so I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed the same symptom - for me, it helped to pass the [`-u`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) argument to the Python interpreter, as in:

```
python -u -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) says:

> Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered. On systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and stderr in binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182541), output buffering is turned on when:

> process STDOUT is redirected to something other than a terminal

The suggested solution would in this case be:

```
stdbuf -oL python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025 > mail.log
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with Flask, I set up a similar SMPTHandler for app.logger.

I found that the output of `python -m smptd` goes to the `stderr` (&2), instead of `stdout` (&1). Although there may be more elegant solutions, this worked for me:

python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer 127.0.0.1:1025 2>&1 >> smtp_error.log

The command sends the `stderr` to `stdout` and then logs all output to the smpt_error.log.